# Navigate between pages in contentplaceholder using UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, master-pages

I have one masterpage:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And also I have 3 pages with navigation buttons Next and Back, something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server">Second PAGE</asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" />
    </div>   
</asp:Content>
```

Could you advise me, please, how to navigate between this pages without loading all page and only overload content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove controls in `ContentPlaceHolderContent` on `btnNext` and `btnBack` `OnClick` events

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanelContent" runat="server">
        <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolderContent" runat="server" />
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  
    <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" OnClick="btnBack_Click"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" OnClick="btnNext_Click"/>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
  protected btnNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     ContentPlaceHolderContent.Controls.Clear();
     Literal l = new Literal();
     l.Text = "new content";
     ContentPlaceHolderContent.Controls.Add(l);
  }

  protected void btnBack_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     ContentPlaceHolderContent.Controls.Clear();
     Literal l = new Literal();
     l.Text = "old content";
     ContentPlaceHolderContent.Controls.Add(l);
  }
```